# Restrict access to SQL Server backups based on user?

Tags: security, file-permissions

Let's say I have MS SQL Server 2012 Standard installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. It's a single SQL instance that runs under the windows domain account DOMAIN\sql_user. There's two databases, db1 and db2. There's two Windows domain accounts that are granted permission to login: DOMAIN\user1 and DOMAIN\user2. user1 has access to db1 and user2 has access to db2; each user cannot access the other's DB. user1 has permission to create DB backups and restore DB backups for db1, user2 has the same for db2. Let's say the backups are saved to D:\SQL\Backups[db1|db2]. How can I restrict what backup files these users can backup/restore to/from so they can only see their respective backup files? Ex, how can I restrict user1 to only restore files from D:\SQL\Backups\db1\ and not from D:\SQL\Backups\db2\, and vice versa for user2?

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the correct NTFS permissions on the folders would do what you want. Has nothing to do with SQL server.

/Edit - looks like I'm wrong. If the access to the BKF is performed by the service account (which does surprise me), then I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want.

Comment: This will work even though the restore operations are performed through SQL server? I want to make sure that running RESTORE as DOMAIN\user1 will restrict access to the appropriate folders.

Comment: I will repeat myself. The SQL operations have *nothing* to do with this. If you have set permissions on the DB1 folder to disallow User2 to read it, then User2 will not be able to access the files in DB1.

Comment: Created a backup of DB 'test' using user DOMAIN\user1. Applied NTFS deny for full control for DOMAIN\user2 to said DB backup folder. Ran a cmd prompt as DOMAIN\user2. user2 is unable to access DB backup folder. From that same cmd prompt, osql command was executed to restore the DB from that path and it was successful.

Comment: I find that odd. I don't have a SQL server in front of me to play with. You could run ProcMon to see what user account is accessing the BKFs during the restore. Was OSQL run as the User2 login, or a SQL login? The User2 login isn't a holder of SQL sysadmin role, is it?

Comment: And you're certain that none of the groups that User2 is a member of have read permissions on the file? Try that - even if User2 can't read the folder, it can be configured that User2 can read a *file* in the folder. It's possible that NTFS permissions inheritance in your environment isn't what I'm assuming it should be.

Comment: We explicitly put NTFS deny for everything on that folder and verified that it inherited on the file. It was running as User2 (trusted auth with osql). I'll double check the account roles tomorrow.

Comment: User2 has no server roles other than public. DB 'test' is owned by User2 (so it can be overwritten without any extra server roles). Backup file had full deny NTFS permissions applied for User2. User2 was successfully able to restore the backup. Procmon shows the restore process accessing the file as the SQL service account (DOMAIN\sql_user) from sqlservr.exe. EDIT: Command was osql -E -S SRV\SQL -Q "RESTORE DATABASE test FROM DISK = 'D:\Test1\test.bak' WITH REPLACE"

Comment: Hm - ok then. If the access to the BKF is performed by the service account (which does surprise me), then I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using two instances of SQLServer you can do that.
Each instance run at diferent SO user, each SO user will be granted with diferent permissions on disk.